# Save as txt with name and file location based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

i need to export as txt some sheets , i can't do it . I try it in that way but don't go to the right file location :

```
Dim filePath As String 
Dim fileName As String 

filePath = Sheet1.Range("B3").Value

fileName = Sheet22.Range("N3").Value

    Sheet14.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
          fileName, 
FileFormat:= _
        xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

it's that correct ?

Comment: ① "*doesn't work*" is a completely meaningless error description. What error do you get and where? ② This is no valid syntax there are no `;` in line endings in VBA.  So this won't even compile. ③ `SaveAs fileName:="C:\My\Example\Path\Filename.txt"` needs to get a full path (not only a filename)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to rename your current worksheets all the time you save them you should try this:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim fileName As String

Sub Export_WS()

Set ws = Worksheets("Exportsheet")

'Get file path your way by this Sub
GetFile

'Copy the ws to a new workbook
ws.Copy

'With the new wb:
With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
'Save and close the new workbook
    .SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
    .Close False
End With

End Sub
```

Here is how I got the file link

```
Function GetFile() As String

Dim filename_path As Variant
filename_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="xyz* (*.txt), *.txt", Title:="Select file")
If filename_path = False Then Exit Function
GetFile = filename_path
fileName = filename_path

End Function
```

Hope that helps.

Or like you suggested by a Cell Value

```
fileName = SheetXYZ.Range("A1").Value
```

Of course you can also assign the filename manually:

```
fileName = "c:filename.txt"
```

Additional Information is here:
[File Operations](https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-to-copy-move-delete-and-manage-files/)